# Move background on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently building a script where the background image moves depending on the location of the mouse. I basically got this effect to work but the problem is that as soon if another div is overlaying it is not working anymore.

In the example (scroll down in snippet) you can see the difference between the two. Maybe somebody knows a solution for this where the background is still triggered on the mouse position but isn't affected because a div is overlaying?

*I can add pointer-events:none to the overlaying div which works but looking for a better solution.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var movementStrength = 50;
  var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
  var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
  
  $(".hover-image").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
    var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
    var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
    var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
    $('.hover-image').css("background-position", newvalueX + "px     " + newvalueY + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.spacer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: black;
}

.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.hover-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random') -25px -50px;
  background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.col-md-12 {
  padding: 300px 0;
}

.col-md-12 span {
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="spacer"></section>
<section class="bg">
  <div class="hover-image"></div>
</section>
<section class="spacer"></section>
<section class="bg">
  <div class="hover-image"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <span>
        BACKGROUND NOT WORKING ANYMORE
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="spacer"></section>
```

Comment: Your snippet only appears to show a black screen for me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, you have to scroll down, I will edit the snippet quickly

Comment: Thanks. Quick fix would be to apply `pointer-events: none` to the `.container` which is shown over the image, but this will mean that no links or form content within the element will be clickable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah I described that quick fix in the description as well haha! Was hoping for a more cleaner solution